# Storing keyvalue as header and value text as rows using data frame in python using beautiful soup

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, beautifulsoup

```
 for imo in imos:
...
...
       keys_div= soup.find_all("div", {"class","col-4 keytext"})
        values_div = soup.find_all("div",{"class","col-8 valuetext"})

        for key, value in zip(keys_div, values_div):
         print(key.text + ": " + value.text)
'......
```

**Output:**

```
Ship Name: MAERSK ADRIATIC
Shiptype: Chemical/Products Tanker
IMO/LR No.: 9636632
Gross: 23,297
Call Sign: 9V3388
Deadweight: 37,538
MMSI No.: 566429000
Year of Build: 2012
Flag: Singapore
Status: In Service/Commission
Operator: Handytankers K/S
Shipbuilder: Hyundai Mipo Dockyard Co Ltd 
ShipType: Chemical/Products Tanker
Built: 2012
GT: 23,297
Deadweight: 37,538
Length Overall: 184.000
Length (BP): 176.000
Length (Reg): 177.460
Bulbous Bow: Yes
Breadth Extreme: 27.430
Breadth Moulded: 27.400
Draught: 11.500
Depth: 17.200
Keel To Mast Height: 46.900
Displacement: 46565
T/CM: 45.0
```

This is the output for one imo, i want to store this output in dataframe and write to csv, the csv will have the keytext as header and value text as rows for all the IMO's please help me on how to do it

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? url? Can you provide 3 or 4 IMOs to test with?

Comment: Its from a paid website. I will get a similar output for each IMO number in the loop.I wanted to store the output in dataframe and csv. for each iteration the key text  will remain the same only the value text will be different hence i want to keep key text as header and value text a each row in a csv

Comment: Will all listings have the same keys and number of keys? Can there be searches that return nothing?

Comment: Yes Qharr, it will have same number of keys which will be headers , yes searches can return null too

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the results to a list and then output that list to a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = r"C\users\test\test_file.csv"
output_data = []

for imo in imos:
    keys_div = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class","col-4 keytext"})]
    values_div = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("div",{"class","col-8 valuetext"})]
    dict1 = dict(zip(keys_div, values_div))
    output_data.append(dict1)

df = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Samt94 it works but the CSV output is each cell has the value pair like below  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 ('Ship Name', 'MAERSK ADRIATIC') ('Shiptype', 'Chemical/Products Tanker') ('IMO/LR No.', '9636632') ('Gross', '23,297') ('Call Sign', '9V3388') ('Deadweight', '37,538') ('MMSI No.', '566429000') ('Year of Build', '2012') ('Flag', 'Singapore') but i need the key to be the header row and values to be in each row

Comment: also when the code loops for 5 imos, the first 4 rows in output csv are blank only the 5th row is being populated as key, value pair in each cell

Comment: current csv output is like below ('Ship Name', 'MAERSK ADRIATIC') ('Shiptype', 'Chemical/Products Tanker') ('IMO/LR No.', '9636632') ('Gross', '23,297') ('Call Sign', '9V3388') ('Deadweight', '37,538') ('MMSI No.', '566429000') ('Year of Build', '2012') ('Flag', 'Singapore')
('Ship Name', 'AL BATEEN') ('Shiptype', 'Crude/Oil Products Tanker') ('IMO/LR No.', '9828376') ('Gross', '65,631') ('Call Sign', '5LBF5') ('Deadweight', '114,637') ('MMSI No.', '636020891') ('Year of Build', '2020') ('Flag', 'Liberia')

 I want  the Keys to be header and the values to be rows. please help

Comment: Sorry I was meant to put dict(zip(keys_div, values_div))